# No puedo llamar un controlador por AJAX en codeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, .htaccess

Estoy pasando mi proyecto a producción, estaba en un ambiente de develop y todo funcionaba correcto (localhost).

Cuando migro a a producción las llamadas por AJAX no encuentran la ruta que necesito.(Error 404)

**EDITO**

La variable 'bu' ya trae la base_url(), pero curiosamente es la IP del servidor y no la url www.misitio.com (por ejemplo)

Este es un ejemplo que está en JS:

```
function callAjax( u, m, d = {}, c, a = true ){

    $.ajax({
      url: bu + u,
      method: m,
      async: a,
      data: d,
      beforeSend: function(){

      },
      complete: function(){

      },

      success: c,

      error: function( e ){
        if( e.status >= 400 && e.status < 500){
            renderMessage( 'Servicio no disponible', 'error' );
        }

        else if (e.status >= 500 && e.status < 600) {
          renderMessage( 'Ocurrió un error en el servidor', 'error' );
        }

      }
    });
  }
  callAjax('Items','GET',null,function( r ){});
```

Este es el controlador de Items

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Items extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('items_model');
    $this->load->helper('query');

    $q = $this->items_model->getItems();
    echo queryToJSON( $q );
  }

}
?>
```

Y por último este es mi .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

No se si tenga que agregar la ruta en el archivo routes.php o en config, no entiendo si funcionaba bien en develop que está pasando en producción.

Gracias

Comment: Hola, estas utilizando la función `base_url` en las urls?

Comment: Si, ya lo agregué, pero sigue sin encontrar :(

Comment: cual es el error que da? (consola javascript) . un `echo base_url('/');` justo antes del javascript que dice? tal vez tengas que setear `$config['base_url']`

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo hago de esta manera:

Mi htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets)
#RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

mi base_url:
**https://mipagina.com/**

mi Ajax:

```
var data = $(".formu").serialize();
            $.post('<?php echo base_url() ?>controlador/funcion',data)
            .done(function(resp){
                $(".resultado").html(resp);
            })
            .fail(function(err){
                $(".resultado").html(err);
            })
```

y todo funciona de maravilla.